# Change orientation with NSNotificationCenter and UIDeviceOrientation

Tags: ios, orientation, nsnotificationcenter, landscape-portrait

Why don´t work when I change the orientation of the simulator in xCode? I see equals the label on the ViewController all time and the NSLog doesn´t appear.

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self orientacionActual];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientacionActual)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(UIDeviceOrientation) orientacionActual
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientacionActual = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    return orientacionActual;
}

- (void) cambiaOrientacion:(NSNotification *) notificación
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([self orientacionActual]))
    {
        self.LabelEstoy.text = @"Landscape";
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
    } else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([self orientacionActual]))
    {
        self.LabelEstoy.text = @"Portrait";
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` instead of device orientation changes. Also, I'm not sure what is your goal, but try to use this snippet:

Inside `viewDidLoad:`

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                      selector:@selector(cambiaOrientacion:)
                          name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                        object:nil];
```

and below:

```
- (void)cambiaOrientacion:(NSNotification *)notificacion
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[[notification userInfo] 
       objectForKey:UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
    {
        self.LabelEstoy.text = @"Landscape";
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
    } else
    {
        self.LabelEstoy.text = @"Portrait";
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
}
```

and `orientacionActual` method redudant in your code, and doesn't makes any sense.

Don't forget to add `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` inside `dealloc`.

Comment: Thanks now work but I don´t need this : `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[[notificación userInfo] objectForKey:UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] integerValue];`The problem was the selector Thanks!

Comment: It's preferably way of getting current orientation.